# How can reviewing be made more efficient?

Tags: feature-request

As suggested by 200_success in a comment to [this answer of mine](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5494/14363), I'm asking this question. For me, missing tools are the biggest problem of this site. *I'd bet that it repels potential reviewers and makes the remaining ones inefficient.*

Obviously, we can't have everything a company using a limited set of languages and strict code conventions can offer, but the SO format is pretty lacking. But there are quite a few programmers here (all of us?) and something should be doable.

#### Colors

As a fundamental part of CR are code changes, there should be a way to distinguish

- old code to be removed
- code to be added
- code to be preserved
- additionally: comments belonging to the CR (rather then to the code)

Maybe a diff-style input like

```
/ Always use braces to avoid bugs.
- for(int i=1;i<5;++i) sum = sum + i;
+ for (int i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
+     sum += i;
+ }
/ This gives us no information, just drop it.
- // Now we're done.
= return sum;
```

could be used for this and display an usual code block, but with let's say blue/red/green/black text. This would make the CR code even a bit harder to write but much easier to read.

#### Preview

As CRs tend to be much longer than typical SO answers, you can't see the formatted output without scrolling a lot. There should be a preview in another window.

#### Other features

There's a lot what could be done, but at least *something* should be done so that we can do more review and less wasting time.

Comment: Does sound like a good [StackApps](http://stackapps.com/) project to create a SE extension for CR to facilitate code-reviewing... hmms, should I dust off my web skillz?

Comment: @h.j.k. Alternatively, a [user script](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78695/code-q2a-copy-code-blocks-from-questions-to-answers) can help with things as well

Comment: I’ve been using [this user script for three columns by CertainPerformance](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Three-Columns) for a while- it works well. I’ve considered modifying Simons code Q2A script to mimic GH code selection UI

Answer (score 15):

Scrolling up and down between the OP and the answer-in-progress is utterly wasteful and annoying.

A work-around I've come to use whenever possible, is to duplicate the browser tab, drag it to a 2nd monitor and work with the OP on one side and my answer-in-progress on the other.

It would be nice to be able to toggle a display mode that splits the page in the middle and puts the OP on the left and the answer on the right, or vice-versa.

Comment: [Can we hide other answers while we are answering?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190136/148099)

Comment: Haha, I usually just overlay my text editor with a half size window over the browser tab. Then copy-paste the markdown when done.

Comment: @200_success it's not about the other answers, it's about a lengthy OP that we want on-screen as we type up our review :-)

Comment: Drag the question browser tab to a 2nd monitor, but that's assuming you don't *already have* The 2nd Monitor chatroom on the 2nd monitor of course. ;)

Comment: @h.j.k. That's where using multiple desktops comes in.

Comment: I did create this tool to help with this a bit: [Code-Q2A - copy code blocks from questions to answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78695/code-q2a-copy-code-blocks-from-questions-to-answers). It is not a perfect solution, but I think it is a step in the right direction.

Comment: @glampert If you're using Firefox, you can get rid of the copy-paste part by using [the It's All Text extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/its-all-text/). There are probably similar extensions for other browsers.

Comment: I actually use this method for all of my StackExchange answering (not that I do it that often). It's more of a problem with CodeReview (I can imagine), but StackOverflow suffers from this problem as well. Perhaps a network-wide 'fullscreen toggle'-like functionality, to have the OP's question/comments on the left, and the answer field on the right, might be a good idea. I'm not a UX guy, but that would be incredibly helpful, mostly for SE sites like SO and CR.

Answer (score 11):

I spend a needless amount of time indenting code by hand because just selecting code and pressing [tab](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tab) does not work. I know that there is [ctrl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ctrl)+[k](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/k) but it only solves half of the problem since it only indents when the code is not indented *enough* (where "enough" is subjective since it will never indent the code enough in a bullet list) and desindents the code otherwise.

I seriously never used the [tab](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tab) button from the main answer field to go to another field, so not having it available to indent and desindent the code it only a bother and a waste of time.

While it's just an issue among others, I feel that it is important considering the amounts of code we have to deal with.

Comment: What I do is add a new line containing a single nonindented character before or after the part I want to indent.  Then I select the block along with the extra line and press ctrl+k.  That indents everything by one level.  Repeat as necessary and then remove all the temporary lines.

Comment: @JS1 That's also what I do from time to time, but I wouldn't call it an optimal solution. It's more of a workaround to try to bypass the real problem.

Comment: Use [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) to install this [extremely handy userscript to enable tab and shift-tab when writing questions and answers](https://bitbucket.org/balpha/se-tab-edting/raw/tip/tab-editing.updating.user.js). It is *essential* for your sanity.